# Standard derivatives from Fragment Shader (dFdx, dFdy), don't run correctly in Android 4.4

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader, android-4.4-kitkat, opengl-es-3.0

I'm using a fragment shader that uses dFdy dFdx functions to calculate the normal of the 
face to view in a flat appearance. This shader has been running ok in gles 2.0 and 3.0. Inexplicably, shader don't work in Android 4.4 ( KitKat - gles3.0 ).

(***Solved!!***.. individual derivatives for each component, solve the problem).

In order check error, i prepared these shaders :

```
//Vertex Shader
#version 300 es
precision highp float;
precision highp int;

uniform mat4 PMatrix;  //Projection Matrix (varies according to camera)
uniform mat4 MVMatrix;  //Model View Matrix (no change)
in vec3 vPosition;
out vec3 vPos;
main()
{
      gl_Position=PMatrix * MVMatrix * vec4(vPosition.xyz,1.0);
      vPos = (MVMatrix * vec4(vPosition.xyz,1.0)).xyz;
}

// Fragment shader
#version 300 es
#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
precision highp float;
precision highp int;
in vec3 vPos;
main()
{
    // don't run correctly
    // vec3 fdx = dFdx(vPos);
    // vec3 fdy = dFdy(vPos);

    // ***Solved!*** this run correctly in KitKat   
    vec3 fdx = vec3(dFdx(vPos.x),dFdx(vPos.y),dFdx(vPos.z));    
    vec3 fdy = vec3(dFdy(vPos.x),dFdy(vPos.y),dFdy(vPos.z));


    vec3 N = normalize(cross(fdx,fdy)); 
    fragColor = vec4(N,1.0);
}
```

Drawing a cube, in Android<4.4 colors remain fixed for each side, independently of camera position (correct, the color identifies each normal-face). In Android 4.4 , colors vary if you move the camera.

Analyzing each derived separately :

1.- `fragColor=vec4(normalize( fdx ), 1.0);` colors are constantly changing (wrong)

2.- `fragColor=vec4(normalize( fdy ), 1.0);` the colors remain quasi-stable (quasi-ok)

A bug in the implementation of these features in Android 4.4?
We are doing something wrong?

Comment: Individual derivatives in each component solve the problem: `vec3 fdx = vec3(dFdx(vPos.x),dFdx(vPos.y),dFdx(vPos.z));`  `vec3 fdy = vec3(dFdy(vPos.x),dFdy(vPos.y),dFdy(vPos.z));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Individual derivatives in each component solve the problem in KitKat:

```
// Replace vec3 fdx = dFdx(vPos)  by:
vec3 fdx = vec3(dFdx(vPos.x),dFdx(vPos.y),dFdx(vPos.z));

// Replace vec3 fdy = dFdy(vPos)  by:
vec3 fdy = vec3(dFdy(vPos.x),dFdy(vPos.y),dFdy(vPos.z));
```

Answer (score 4):

You said that this was originally a GLES2 shader, and you are using `highp` in a fragment shader unconditionally? That is a disaster waiting to happen because GLES2 implementations are not required to support `highp` in fragment shaders. Likewise, support for `dFdx (...)`, `dFdy (...)` and `fwidth (...)` is optional.

You need to check for `GL_OES_standard_derivatives` and `GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH` in the GLES2 implementation of this fragment shader.

To that end, you might consider the accuracy hint for derivatives:

- `GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER_DERIVATIVE_HINT_OES`  (GLES2, if the extension is supported)
- `GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER_DERIVATIVE_HINT`          (GLES3)

Comment: Yes, the shader exposed is only a "demo". Really the final sample use: `#version 300 es`  `#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable` 
`precision highp float;`
`precision highp int;`. I have not tried to activate the HINT. I test

Comment: Checking by `GLES30.glHint(GLES30.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER_DERIVATIVE_HINT, GLES30.GL_NICEST);` and `GL_FASTEST`,`GL_DONTCARE` don't solve the problem. Annotation: The Tested hardware, supports `GL_OES_standard_derivatives` and `GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH`  extensions in 4.3 and 4.4, but in 4.4 not work properly: I Tested on S4-I9505 (4.3 and 4.4), Nexus 4 (4.3 and 4.4) and Nexus 5 (4.4)

Comment: Individual derivatives in each component solve the problem: `vec3 fdx = vec3(dFdx(vPos.x),dFdx(vPos.y),dFdx(vPos.z));`  `vec3 fdy = vec3(dFdy(vPos.x),dFdy(vPos.y),dFdy(vPos.z));`

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar things on some AMD desktop setups.

Where dFdy( .xyz ) worked fine on NVIDIA/intel I had to do the derivate per-component to get it correctly for some AMD cards.